# Where should keyboard focus after closing a dialog with the button opening the dialog removed?

Tags: accessibility, html5

In the UI design, each item panel contains a remove button. If clicking the remove button, a confirmation dialog would prompt. If cancel, the keyboard would focus back to the remove button. If confirm, the item would be removed, so the remove button in the panel which open the confirmation dialog would also be removed. In this case, where should the keyboard focus after the item removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus should go to the next item. In that way you can go easily go through each item and delete it.

Comment: Do you mean the delete button of the next item or the next item itself?

Comment: I don't know which actions are available besides delete. If delete is the only action, yes, focus on that. The problem with the word 'focus' is that for web, it's very specific to form elements and an *item* is not a form element and thus can't be focused, unless you mean a checkbox?

Comment: Yes, the delete is the only action, which is a button. And the item is a div. I didn't add tabindex to div, so it will focus on the next delete button.

Comment: In that case it make sense to focus on the next delete button. I don't see how adding focus to the item does something useful for the user. The confusion here is that focus can mean a visual style, rather than an actual HTML form focus.

Comment: Got it. I mean a visual style, like a blue outline surrounding the button, not a form focus into an input field. Thanks!

Comment: If deleting is the main purpose of that list, then focus on the delete button.

Comment: +1 for the emphasis on being able to easily go through the list and delete multiple items. The exact control the focus returns to is less important than facilitating the likely interactions.